# Having trouble installing new theme (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, themes, gnome, gnome-3

I'm attempting to install the 'Iris Dark' theme on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine.
I'm using gnome-3, and the gnome tweak tool.

I've downloaded, extracted and then moved the theme into my theme folder like so.

```
unzip /home/admin/Desktop/IrisDark.zip /home/admin/Desktop/IrisDark
sudo cp -r /home/admin/Desktop/IrisDark /usr/share/themes
```

When I check the gnome tweak tool, it doesn't show up as a theme for either 'Windows' or GTK+. I am able to install other themes using the same method, only having trouble with this specific one.

When I try to open the folder I've just copied in my themes folder, I get 'This location could not be displayed, you do not have the nessecary permissions.."

This does not happen with any other themes I move into that folder, I only lack the read permission for this particular theme. I assume that the tweak tool is also running into that permissions error, and that's why it can't find it, I don't have any idea how I could fix this though.

EDIT: Moving the zipped file to the themes folder, and then unzipping it produces the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was eventually fixed by creating my own themes folder, which I had permissions over.

```
cd ~
mkdir .themes
cp -r /home/admin/Desktop/IrisDark ~/.themes
```

Turns out your not supposed to use the systems themes folder, but create your own.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same challenge. I will like to state the procedures that I took to make mine to work, and then you can check to see if you got it wrong somewhere.

**Here are the steps**

First install the Gnome Tweak Tool from the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Next, go to GNOME website [GNOME Website](https://www.gnome-look.org/) and download the theme of your choice. They are usually in zipped files, and may be in various variants.

Extract the downloaded files to the **~/.themes/ (home/.themes)** directory - to install for current user only. You can press Ctrl + H to show hidden folders. Create the themes folder if you don't have it yet.

Or sudo extract them to the **/usr/share/themes/ (home/usr/share/themes)** folder - to apply them globally.

```
sudo tar -xf Folder-Name.tar.xz -C /usr/share/themes
```

Restart GNOME Tweaks tool. You should see the manually installed GNOME themes in the Tweak tool now. You can configure or enable the newly installed themes here.

This technique for **GTK Themes** also applies for **Icon Themes**

That's all

**I hope this helps**